# Second SD not writing

Tags: arduino-ide, sd-card

simple problem I can't see the reason behind, the sd card writes the first file fine, but the second doesn't write at all. Can any one see why?

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    const int chipSelect = BUILTIN_SDCARD;
    File datafile;
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(38400);
      analogReadResolution(13);
      //Initialize SPI pins to avoid errors
      //USB host SS pin
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(chipSelect, HIGH);
      delay(200);


      Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

      // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
      if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
       Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  File dFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  dFile.println("BORK");
  dFile.close();
  char filename[] = "LOGGER00.CSV";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    filename[6] = i / 10 + '0';
    filename[7] = i % 10 + '0';
    if (! SD.exists(filename)) {
      datafile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
      break;  // leave the loop!
    }
  }
  Serial.println(filename);
  datafile.print("A0,");
  datafile.println("A1");
  if (!datafile){
    Serial.println("oopsydaisy");
  }
}


void loop()
{
  Serial.print("analog 0 is: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
  Serial.print("analog 1 is: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(1));

  datafile.print(String(analogRead(0)));
  datafile.print(",");
  datafile.print(String(analogRead(1)));
  datafile.println();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: please correct the title of your post .... right now it says that the `second SD card does not work` .... anyone searching for solution to issues with writing  multiple files will miss your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cut your code down to the bare minimum.  You need to work out if:

- It's the fact that it's the second file you're opening that causes it to fail, or
- It's the way you're building up the filename in your loop, or
- It's the way you're handling the file once it's been opened.

You should add extra debugging to your program so you know how your loop is operating. Is it checking for the existence of the files correctly? Is it looping too far? Not at all? Is the filename being created properly?

You haven't properly described your symptoms. Does the file actually get created? If so, is it just that it is empty? (I suspect so).

Why do I suspect that?  Simple:

The SD library uses a certain amount of crude caching. Nothing gets written to the SD card itself until either a whole block of data (512 bytes) has been written, or you close the file. Or manually `flush` the data to the card.

When doing periodic writing to a file like that it is better to open the file as `(O_READ | O_WRITE | O_APPEND)` before each block of writes, then close it afterwards. This ensures that the file is in a good state between each sampling period and all the data is written and the FAT updated properly.

So your method should be:

1. Find your unused filename.
2. Open the file `FILE_WRITE` (or `(O_READ | O_WRITE | O_CREAT)` - different versions of the library define it slightly differently) to make the file.
3. Close the file.

Then on each loop iteration where you want to write:

1. Open the file again as `(O_READ | O_WRITE | O_APPEND)`
2. Write your data.
3. Close the file.

Comment: @Juraj Regardless of whether it has append or not, it has `O_CREAT`, so it will make the file if it's not there - so it will always succeed on the first file whether it exists or not.

Comment: but I see no such operation in his code. and it was not edited

Comment: @Juraj Oh, hang on... All that extra irrelevant code was blinding me with extraneous file opens. Buried deep in there is actually an "exists" that I didn't see before... woods... trees... just goes to show the importance of the SSCCE concept instead of just dumping reams of irrelevant code on us.

Comment: @trinityalps, what was the problem? What from Majenko's answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

You do not close the second file.

The examples show that you should close the file after every write and open it again before next write. Opening the file with SD library using FILE_WRITE flags, opens it for append if the file exists.

In [my project](https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/blob/master/Regulator/CsvLog.ino) I have a MCU with enough RAM (Mega, esp8266 or M0) so I cache the rows into 2000 bytes buffer and write them to file if the memory cache is full.